# Batch insert in neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, batch-insert

I'm trying to batch insert data in neo4j with java. I've found the BatchInserter class but it's deleted.
Has anyone got something else in mind?
Thank you!

Comment: You can check this blog post also: http://maxdemarzi.com/2012/07/02/batch-importer-part-3/

Answer (score 1):

Start with org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserters